# Inductance of a relay coil

Tags: relay, inductance, coil

I'm using a magnetic latching dpdt relay from Teledyne company. The value of inductance for the coil in the relay is needed and not given in the data sheet. The part number of relay is [422d from Teledyne](http://www.willow.co.uk/420-422.pdf).

How can I know it?
Is it possible to know the value without actually buying the product and testing?

Comment: part number of relay is 422d from teledyne

Comment: How about a hyperlink?

Comment: www.teledynerelays.com/pdf/electromechanical/420422.pdf

Comment: The inductance is not specified it seems so why do you need it?

Comment: i need it because the driver that i'm using for the relay is a simple n-mosfet and it is to be designed based on the inductance value of the coil.

Comment: The dominant impedance in the coil is its self resistance - this dictates current flow not the inductance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23945/discussion-between-student-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Sorry I can't do that - I don't have log-in details and unfortunately I haven't the time. What is it that you are worried about?

Comment: Take a look at the upper left hand corner of [this](http://www.teledynerelays.com/). If they can't tell you maybe you can get a sample...

Comment: Actually I have the same question as @Naveen. I need to model a relay in LTSpice and without the coil inductance I'm forced to set it to 0 H and assume it is negligible... Since datasheets do not even bother to show it one could think it is indeed negligible, however, if you don't put a flyback diode you can clearly see that the inductive kickback is there.. I suggest you to use an oscilloscope if you have one.. feed a square wave in, then calculate the time constant, since you know the R of the coil you're pretty much done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple N channel MOSFET driving the relay will not care about the inductance - the final and full value of current the FET sees will be determined solely by the supply voltage and the coil resistance. All that the inductance can do is slow the current down a few milliseconds before it reaches the final value.

This applies whether it is a logic gate, a BJT or a switch; it's simple ohms law: -

I = V/R where V is the supply voltage and R is the coil resistance. The data sheet even tells you what this current will be so no need to do the calculation.

Make sure you use a back-emf diode though or when you open circuit the coil there will likely be a big spike of voltage (due to the inductance) that can easily damage a FET or BJT.

Comment: i'll improve my question..actually we don't want current to flow all the time as we have power constraints.So for that we just want current to flow for some 20ms for which we are putting a capacitor at emitter. henceforth we need the inductance value.

Comment: I don't think you will need to the inductance value because the resistor will still dominate. Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: yeah! it's almost independent of inductance value.i've tried simulating the circuit.Thank you very much

Comment: @student I don't know if you are aware of the conventions on EE - an answer deemed correct by the questioner (you in this case) *can* be marked as "accepted" but there is no hurry of course. Usually waiting a day will give a chance for others to answer if there's a more valid answer to be given.

Answer (score 0):

1.Electromagnetic  Ralay coil has two values: a. when contancts not activated (Low value). b, contacts activated (high value) because the magnetic circuits are different for ON & OFF states. vtingole